# Using ForkJoin to search a string in cube (3D-dimension) is a good choice?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool, fork-join

I'm doing with parallel programming project. The requirement is to search a list of string in a lattice of cube (3D-dimension and maximum is 1000 elements). The max size of list is 1000 and the max length of string is 100.

I create 3 ForkTask: search in X-Dimension(NxN 2D-array), in Y-Dimension(NxN 2D-array), in Z-Dimension(NxN 2D-array). For each Task, I start searching the string in 2D-array and I create a ForkTask for this. I had a function to search a string in 2D-array.

I see that I have a lot of ForkTask as well as thread. To improve the search performance and time reduction, I check that if a task.join() is true, I will cancel the rest of tasks.

Is it a wise approach? Anyone can give me any recommendation or suggestion or advice?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want aid or guidance or help?

Comment: any thing I can do. actually, aid, guidance or help == help :)

Answer (score 0):

Identify what is a job in your project. Let's say, searching in one dimension is a job. Implement your jobs a runnables and execute them in an Executor. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html
If there are more than 3 core, you could also use a job for each slice of each dimension. If your jobs are very fast (under 10µs), the overhead of your job queue maybe too big.